# carousel , increase display image numbers

Tags: jquery, carousel

is anyone able to help me to increase the display image number 5 from 3 at carousel.

I am using the following files

jquery.jcarousel
jquery.jcarousel.min

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [the documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration) of the library.

You should look for the ***visible*** option to set how many items you want to show and the ***scroll*** option to set how many items to skip (increase this accordingly).
You may need to edit the CSS of skin and tweak the width too!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the `scroll` parameter and then edit the css to show the right width.

```
scroll: 5,
```

then edit the css